# How come there are missing entities in this SPARQL query?

Tags: wikidata, sparql, wikipedia, rdf

I was interested in listing all books,
so I wrote:

```
SELECT ?book ?url WHERE {
?book wdt:P31 wd:Q571 .

OPTIONAL {
  ?url schema:about ?book .
  ?url schema:inLanguage "en" .
  ?url schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikipedia.org/> .
}}
```

but somehow this cute book which I read in the past **"The Little Prince"** was missing, although
[Q25338](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q25338) it appears in wikidata.

The Wikipedia page exists too:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Little_Prince

I searched for it in the results, and couldn't find it.

So how come I can't see this book?
Are there any explanations?

Comment: Did you mean `wdt:P31*`? Also, as https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q571 shows, book is a subclass of other classes, and Q25338 is listed as a 'literary work' not a 'book', so maybe broaden your search to parent classes of Q571?